# How to add additional lines and labels on a drawing of a regular hexagon?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I have been able to draw a regular hexagon with the nodes as black dots as you may obtain from this code. I was wondering if there would be a way to draw the image given in the hand-drawn picture. The red lines starting from the vertices outside of the regular hexagon form parallel lines with the other red lines in the given image. The outer vertices are also exactly the radius of the hexagon away from the hexagon. I would see if it would be possible to add labels for the points outside of the hexagon as well as the lines given in the hand drawn image (i.e. the red and green lines as well as the extended diameter, this can be left black).

```
\begin{tikzpicture} \newdimen\R
   \R=1.3cm
   \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:\R) };
   \foreach \x/\l/\p in
     { 60/,
      120/,
      180/,
      240/,
      300/,
      360/
     }
     \node[inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill] at (\x:\R) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code uses polar coordinates with a certain radius, all you have to do is to double the radius for the special points.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=1.3;},
    dot/.style={inner sep=1pt,circle,draw,fill},
    rp/.style={red,edge node={node[pos=0.5,sloped,black]{$\parallel$}}}]
  \draw (0:R) foreach \x [count=\y] in {60,120,...,360} {  -- (\x:R) 
  node[dot] (p\y){} }
  (60:2*R) node[dot] (q1) {} edge[green!70!black] (p3) edge[green!70!black] (p5)
  (240:2*R) node[dot] (q2) {} edge[green!70!black] (p2) edge[green!70!black] (p6)
   edge[rp] (p3) edge[rp] (p5)
  (p4)  edge[rp] (p2) edge[rp] (p6);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way of adding the black diameter given in my hand-drawn picture?

Comment: @causalityrefilm. Yes, add `(q1) edge (q2)` before the `;`.